# laravel adminlte css path not working

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

i am beginner in laravel , im doing my project. but admin lte css path not working.. i had tried many time. but no lock..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koWS8.png)

i create a folder css on project root folder. i put all css and js file in it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elM8Y.png)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/dist/AdminLTE.min.css') }}">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css"> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css') }}">
```

but nothing show...

but whenever i try delete all folder like bootstrap and dist.

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/AdminLTE.css') }}">
```

is work
how to implements css and js file with folder name.

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is easy way to implement AdminLTE for Laravel 5

https://almsaeedstudio.com/blog/integrate-adminlte-with-laravel
and don't forget to Change it to `<script src="{{ asset (" bower_components="" adminlte="" plugins="" jquery="" jquery-2.1.4.min.js")="" }}"=""></script>`

there's no 2.1.3 in directory. the file is 2.1.4 or check the directory.
if you not intrest then wright click the view **inspect** you will get path then correct the way you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Your assets should be in the `public` folder, so move `css` folder with all the contents into `public`

Comment: i did it but same result

Answer (score 0):

Make a css folder inside the public folder
Make a js Foler inside the public folder

change those links to

css files goes like this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-style-css' href='{{ url("css/nameofthefiler.css") }}' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

js files goes like this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='{{ url("js/jsfilename.js") }}'></script>
```

This works for me 
btw i guess what you are doing is accessing files in the `resources/assets` (not sure tho) but whats son the aboves works 100%