# Adminlte script is not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, adminlte

I follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CowsopJhX3M&list=PLB4AdipoHpxaHDLIaMdtro1eXnQtl_UvE&index=2) and its work well, but when I am trying to try like **date-picker** or **multiple select** its not working. I check google crome console but I see no error.

I am using Laravel 6.* and Adminlte 3

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AdminLTE 3 | Advanced form elements</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css')}}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/fontawesome.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-primary">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Date picker</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <!-- Date range -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Date range:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control float-right" id="reservation">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Date and time range:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control float-right" id="reservationtime">
              </div>
            </div>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js')}}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of date-picker and console.

[image]

I found this and its not working for me

[laravel adminlte css path not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993095/laravel-adminlte-css-path-not-working)

Comment: The script on the video is not working for me so I manually use <script src="{{ asset(' URL OF ADMINLTE PLUGIN ')}}"></script> this is the alternative solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try to add this before you render the input field "reservationtime".

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#reservationtime').datepicker();
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but after i put it i got a error: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function... This error occurred when script plugs itself into jQuery so it becomes undefined, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207203/uncaught-typeerror-datepicker-is-not-a-functionanonymous-function